# Vectorized way to find if 1 value in row from list of columns is greater than threshold

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am new to using `np.where()`, so of course I tried to use my new toy for this problem. But it does not work.

I have a dataframe.

```
Close  M    N    O    P
0.1   0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5
0.2   0.1  0.6  0.1  0.0

Colslist = [M,N,O,P]
```

I want a new column called Q with the result of this formula.  The formula I thought up is:

```
df["Q"] = np.where(df[Colslist] >= (Close + 0.3), 1,0)
```

The output would be a 1 in both rows. In row 0 there are 2 values greater than, and row 1 there is 1 value greater than.

I believe the problem in what I wrote is it requires all values to be greater than to output a 1.

So what I am needing is a 1 in Q column if there is a single value in that row for the list of columns that is greater than equal to close of the same row + 0.3.

What's the best vectorized way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the axes don't match in your condition. The output of

```
df[Colslist] >= (df['Close'] + 0.3)
```

is

```
       M      N      O      P      0      1
0  False  False  False  False  False  False
1  False  False  False  False  False  False
```

which doesn't make sense.

You could use `ge` method to make sure that you're comparing values in `Colslist` with "Close" column values. So the result of:

```
df[Colslist].ge(df['Close'] + 0.3, axis=0)
```

is

```
       M      N      O      P
0  False  False   True   True
1  False   True  False  False
```

Now, since your condition is that it is True if there is at least one True in a row, you can use `any` on `axis=1`. Then the final code:

```
Colslist = ['M','N','O','P'] 
df["Q"] = np.where(df[Colslist].ge(df['Close'] + 0.3, axis=0).any(axis=1), 1,0)
```

Output:

```
   Close    M    N    O    P  Q
0    0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4  0.5  1
1    0.2  0.1  0.6  0.1  0.0  1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one-liner with pure `Pandas` so you don't need to convert between `NumPy` and `Pandas` (might help with speed if your dataframe is really long):

```
df["Q"] = (df.max(axis=1) >= df["Close"] + 0.3).astype(int)
```

It finds the max value in each row and sees if it's larger than the required value. If the max value isn't large enough, then no value in the row will be. It takes advantage of the fact that you don't actually need to count the number of elements in a row that are greater than `df["Close"] + 0.3`; you just need to know if at least 1 element meets the condition.

Then it converts the `True` and `False` answers to `1` and `0` using `astype(int)`.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.  I actually tried this, but I need the min value that is greater than Close to be greater than Close+0..3.  In other words, there can be no number between the Close and Close+3 is what I am trying to get at.